# Azure exception only when deployed on server, not on localhost

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I try to connect to an azure table storage and add an object. it works great on localhost, however on a server i use i get the following exception + its inner exception:

```
    Exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageClientException' was thrown.
System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. 
---> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException: 
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
     <error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
     <code>AuthenticationFailed</code>
     <message xml:lang="en-US">Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:17..127 Time:2011-12-16T15:47:50.7505473Z</message>
     </error>
     at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[T](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
     at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
     at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudTableClient.GetResultOrDefault[T](Task`1 task, T& result)
```

my connection string:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=nameoftable;AccountKey=accountkey...
```

Comment: Please share your service configuration. Are you passing the server creds instead of the dev storage credentials?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a bit of a long shot, but check the clock on the server your site is being hosted on.  Part of the [authentication header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179428.aspx) for all Azure storage REST calls is the current UTC.  If this is too far out from what the Azure servers say is the UTC time you'll get that error.

Comment: Amazingly! this was problem & solution!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your data connection string in Role's Settings. I am pretty much sure that either you have mistaken the storage account key, or you left the default connection string "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"

There are no firewall rules that apply to Azure storage, just the account for access. You must create a storage, if you haven't done that already. I suggest that you create your storage in the same data center as your hosted service to avoid traffic charges. Then just use that storage account and key provided in the portal.

[image]

A typical real azure storage account connection string would look something like this:

*DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME;AccountKey=YOUR_ACCOUNT_KEY_BE_IT_PRIMARY_OR_SECONDARY==*

Comment: I already have a storage. when I access it through localhost (i still access the online storage) it works fine. when i try to access it from the server i'm using i get the exception i showed

Comment: my connection string looks like that exactly. also tried with or without https

Comment: Is this connection string in your Cloud config? There are two .cscfg files -> YourProjectName.Cloud.cscfg and YourProject.Local.cscfg. When you say you are trying locally and it works, are you trying with .Local config (default). But when you deploy, the .Cloud.cscg (which is being used by default) might still have the "usedevelopmentstorage=true". You can check the real configuration from the developer portal. Select the Hosted service, which is deployed and click "Configure" icon from the ribbon. It will popup a window with the configuration file. Double check the connection string there.

Comment: this is not a cloud application. it is a normal .net website. i use azure cloud storage only. so i use the connection string not as part of a config but as part of the web application. when i run the web on my own computer it works. when i upload the files to a host i'm using it doesn't work from there

Comment: Very important note. Than you shall contact your hosting provider support to ask them whether they are stripping something from the outbound packets. It is very likely that there is a filtering on outgoing connections to prevent malicious scripts, spam bots etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. the weird thing is that it worked until a day ago.. and I thought I made some kind of change so i rolled back a lot, and nothing..